# What python version does Catkin require?

Tags: python, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a non-debian OS (`QNX` 6.5) where default `Python` version is 2.5. What version of `python` is required to get `catkin` run (meanwhile I try to upgrade the python's version and port `catkin` for it)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64874/what-python-version-does-catkin-require?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin requires python 2.7, which is the minimum version set out in REP 3:

http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#groovy-galapagos-oct-2012

It *might* work with python 2.6, but I couldn't promise this.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-12**:
Has it been tested with Python 3.2 or 3.3?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-12**:
It is not regularly tested on Python 3.2 or 3.3. Parts are tested (`catkin_pkg`) regularly: https://travis-ci.org/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg `catkin_pkg` is known to be failing on 3.3